# Stores writable not updating value correctly?

Tags: typescript, electron, svelte

The problem is that, as of now, the `loadedModule` variable updates correctly and `userSettings` (which is the variable im having this problem with) doesn't update in the frontend at all.

I'm using an external file to update that variable and it works well with that file, but not in the .svelte file.

`stores.ts` file:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron/renderer')
import { Module } from './ts/Module'
import { UserSettings } from './ts/types/UserSettings'

import { Writable, writable } from 'svelte/store'

let mod: Module = null
export const loadedModule: Writable<Module> = writable(new Module('null', 'null', 'null', []))
loadedModule.subscribe(value => {
    console.log("new module updated")
    mod = value
})

let user: UserSettings
export const userSettings: Writable<UserSettings> = writable({zoomLevel:0, version:'b', dataPath:'null'})
userSettings.subscribe(value => {
    console.log("new settings updated")
    user = value
})

export function updateUserSettings(): void {
    userSettings.set(user)
}

export async function loadCurrentModule(module: string): Promise<void> {
    ipcRenderer.invoke('get-module', module).then((res) => {
        if (res != null) {
            loadedModule.set(Module.fromType(res))
        } else {
            console.error('Error while attempting to load a module: ' + module)
        }
    })
}

export async function saveCurrentModule(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise(async () => {
        ipcRenderer.send('save-module', mod.toType())
    })
}
```

`file.ts` sample set call:

```
...
import { userSettings } from './stores'
...

...
const zoomIn = () => {
    console.log("+")
    this.userSettings.zoomLevel++
    if (this.userSettings.zoomLevel > 5) this.userSettings.zoomLevel = 5
    userSettings.set(this.userSettings)
}
...
```

`.svelte` file:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { loadedModule, userSettings, loadCurrentModule, saveCurrentModule } from '../electron/stores'
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    onMount(()=>{
        loadCurrentModule("testmodule")
    })
    
    setTimeout(async ()=>{
        await saveCurrentModule();
    }, 4000)
</script>

<div>
    <p>UserSettings: {$userSettings.zoomLevel}</p>  
    <p>LoadedModule: {$loadedModule.name}</p>
</div>
```

I'm sorry if this post already got too long, but I seriously didnt find a solution and I'm currently thinking this may be because I'm using the `userSetting.set()` function in a file other than `stores.ts` but can't understand why that wouldn't work...

Comment: Why are you subscribing and assigning the a local variable everywhere ? you can simply do `<p>UserSettings: {$userSettings.zoomLevel}</p>` I would advice by removing all these unnecessary reassignments and work directly with the store, your code will be a lot simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: @StephaneVanraes Yes, that is true! I was using that syntax before but I changed it to this one while testing. I can't change it in stores tho, but I'll stick to your method on .svelte files. Thanks!
Changed the question to reflect the edit.

Answer (score 1):

to update stores you correctly use `.set` but what does your data being set look like? since userSettings is a writable store, you can't just access the data in it and I'm not sure what your `this` looks like in the file.ts. Something that may help out is to do more verbose logging.

```js
import { userSettings } from './stores'

const zoomIn = () => {
    console.log("+", this.userSettings); // what's here?
    this.userSettings.zoomLevel++
    if (this.userSettings.zoomLevel > 5) this.userSettings.zoomLevel = 5
    userSettings.set(this.userSettings);
}

// also log the value when subscribing

userSettings.subscribe(value => {
    console.log("new settings updated", value); // log the value
    user = value
});
```